# Low water pressure all over house after trip

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

We just went away for 1 week and when we came back, the water pressure was low all over the house. We do not have a pressure regulator (at least I can't see it before or after the meter where the water pipe comes up from the slab). We do not have a whole house water filter. The neighbors haven't noticed any pressure issues. We do not have a leak (leak detector dial on the meter is not spinning when all faucets are closed). The flow at the bath tub spout is only about 0.8 gpm. I don't have a pressure gauge, so haven't measured pressure yet. When we flush the toilet there is almost no water coming out of the bathroom faucet. When I open the outside hose bib, which is hooked in directly after the meter, I get a burst of water, which slows down to a trickle after 7 seconds, and there is some sputtering. See video here: https://youtube.com/shorts/FyqyGpDyKFE?feature=share

Pipe are all copper as far as I can tell. House was built in 1980. Climate is New Jersey, so it has been 30-50F, but no significant hard frost.

I did not shutoff water to the whole house before my trip. Only shutoff water to the laundry. I open and closed the shut-off valve after the meter to see if that helped, but it didn't.

Could it be the water meter? Any advice on troubleshooting?

Thanks
[image: main water meter]

Comment: It looks like your meter is broke

Comment: I will take a SWAG and say the galvanized pipe if clossing closed.

Comment: Given you are on some sort of water service, I'd suggest calling them, as you have some srt of flow restriction, based on the hose bibb behavior - lots of pressure followed by no pressure is a restriction. Given that's right after the meter, there's a problem that's probably worth having them take a look at. ...you have paid your water bill?

Comment: @Ecnerwal yes, I have paid my bill ;-). I called the utility and they will come out in 1 week to check the meter. I really hope it is the meter and not a leak in the slab. I checked the pressure and it shows 60 psi, but as soon as I open a nearby faucet it drops to <20 psi. I hope water company doesn’t just check static pressure and leave.

Comment: Moderately joking, but if they had shut you off and the valve they used leaked a bit, you'd see similar behavior, so worth eliminating as a possible cause.